# Issues making integration test work when using WithWebHostBuilder combined with Hangfire

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing, xunit, hangfire

I have a single method that uses a custom `CustomWebApplicationFactory` that calls

```
services.AddHangfire(configure => configure.UseInMemoryStorage()).AddHangfireServer(configuration =>
{
  configuration.WorkerCount = 1;
  configuration.Queues = new[] {"critical", "default" };
});
```

And then in the method itself I call `WithWebHostBuilder` to dynamically change the connection string used for the integration test.

What follows is that my job storage always contains 0 jobs. Calling `JobStorage.Current`, or `factory.Services.GetRequiredService<JobStorage>()` yields in the same empty storage, whereas if I remove the `WithWebHostBuilder` call and skip creating a second WebHost, everything works as expected when testing - both calls point to a store that contains the jobs I've run in the integration test.

Both cases execute the jobs in question, so I'm guessing due to the nature of how `WithWebHostBuilder` does its thing, there are actually 2 In-Memory hangfire methods/servers registered, and as such, the first server takes the load, and I'm left holding an empty storage.

Is this what's going on? If so, how can I go about fixing the issue, other than creating a custom Fixture containing an instance of my custom `WebApplicationFactory` for **EVERY** connection string I'm testing? This would require extensive refactoring, as then I can't use inline data, and I'd have to make an internal method that would work with a single such instance, as otherwise I'd have to duplicate my integration test for every single instance.

I'd love to avoid the above scenario!

Comment: We are having the same problem :) Add logging to your CustomWebApplicationFactory
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{
    services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole().AddDebug());
});

Answer (score 0):

Three things to try:

1. Try and remove the `Hangfire` configuration loaded in your `Program.cs` before modifying `AddHangfire`. I think the "GlobalConfiguration" type is correct for `Hangfire`...

I think you might be creating BOTH the original and the new `WebApplicationFactory` one?

```
    builder.ConfigureServices(services => {

    services.RemoveAll(typeof(GlobalConfiguration));

    services.AddHangfire(config => config
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
        .UseMemoryStorage());
   });
```

2. Make sure you are running the correct environment variable if you have settings for Local, Development, QA, Production in `Program.cs` The default value for `WebApplicationFactory` is "Development".

   ```
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {

     builder.UseEnvironment("Local");        // Default setting is to use Development environment

     base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

     builder.ConfigureServices(services => {

         services.RemoveAll(typeof(GlobalConfiguration));
         services.AddHangfire(config => config
             .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
             .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
             .UseMemoryStorage());
     });
   }
   ```
3. Logging and Testing

Also, you can put breakpoints in your `Program.cs` and then step through the code by choosing "Debug tests" when running your unit/integration tests. You can then see what is being modified by your `WebApplicationFactory` and what is remaining as normal and where it is breaking.

Also add logging inside `builder.ConfigureTestServices()`

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
 {

     builder.UseEnvironment("Local");

     base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

     builder.ConfigureServices(services => {

         services.RemoveAll(typeof(GlobalConfiguration));
         services.AddHangfire(config => config
             .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
             .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
             .UseMemoryStorage());
     });
    
    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
    // Put mocks here
    //services.AddSingleton(your_mocks);
    services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole().AddDebug());        // Any issues, check the output window to see where the build is failing.
    });
}
```

Comment: The issiue still exists - the first test always passes, but the second time I run a test, it fails because the assert on how many jobs were queued is always 0. I think everything just gets routed to the first instance

Comment: After caching the first test's WebHostBuilder, it seems they're not routed there, so I have no idea what's going on - adding Debug logging doesn't seem to produce anything useful

Comment: Perhaps it's still my initial hypothesis at hand - it's just that the second reigstration of the webhost, replaces even the references to the first instance's JobStorage provider?